# Rtrim() in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using trim() in twig file but this is trim both beginning and last world.
I want to trim only last world.

Like in php use rtrim().

How it's possible in twig file ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

{{ '  I like Twig.  '|trim(' ', 'right') }}
{# outputs '  I like Twig.' #}

As per the [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/trim.html).

Answer (score 0):

What i wrote with the `truncate` isn't working. You have to write a new filter or function.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

There you can use the `rtrim` and return the result. Then you can call it `{{ myvar|rtrim }}`

Comment: Thanks for answer, Can you give me one example in Twig file ?